# Classic ASP How to refer to a field I altered with LEFT

Tags: sql, asp-classic, adodb

I'm trying to get the left 7 characters of a column, and the entirety of a second column from a table in my database. The code I am using to do this looks like this (minus the connection string, don't want to give that away).

```
Set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
conn.Open "myConnectionString"
Set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rs.Open "SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(Location,7), StopID FROM LocStop", conn

do until rs.eof
    Response.Write(rs("Location"))
    Response.Write(rs("StopID"))
    rs.movenext
loop
```

This gives the error "ADODB.Recordset error '800a0cc1'
Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal." on the line `Response.Write(rs("Location"))`. Using `rs.fields("Location")` fails in the same way

When I run this code without the LEFT call it works fine. My guess is that the column name Location is either not taken or is changed when I use LEFT on it. I am at a loss as to how I am now supposed to get this information now. Does anyone know if my guess was correct, and how get the information I need?

Comment: Once you turn a column into a computed column *(apply some function to it to change the result)* you are no longer referencing that particular column but a now separate computed column which needs to be aliased. However there is no reason not to use the existing column name i.e `LEFT(Location, 7) [Location]` will work for example.

Comment: Yet another possible duplicate [ASP Classic recordset unable to see columns with 'table.column_name' format after MySQL conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33263086/692942) *(ignore the MySQL part same issue still applies across multiple providers that use ADODB)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of ways:

- Give it an *alias*:

  ```
  SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(Location,7) as Location, StopID 
  FROM LocStop
  ```

  And then refer it using the alias name:

  ```
  Response.Write(rs("Location"))
  ```
- Or you could reference it by its index: (field name won't matter)

  ```
  Response.Write(rs(0))
  ```

Comment: This isn't something new and has been answered lots of times before.